# Ubuntu programs won't run from command line but say they are installed

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to Linux and non-Microsoft web development (long time MS developer). I am making some kind of fundamental mistake when I install Linux programs but I don't know what.

I am trying to install spring-boot-cli for use to make a Java microservice. I am just trying to learn how. I followed the installation instructions I found here, ending up using the SDKMAN installation method: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html

When I try to run `spring --version`, it says spring is not installed. When I go back and try to install it again, sdk says, "STOP!  this is already installed."

I am having a similar problem with Maven. I try to run command line commands and it is not recognized, but it claims it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit unusual but at the terminal type:

```
> which spring
```

and then

```
> $PATH
```

should give you a starting point.

Comment: what should I get back? I got back a collection of paths and the message, "No such file or direcoty"

Comment: sorry been away for a bit - so that means that it is not installed - do you know where the binary for spring is located? If yes, you could try running with full path.

Comment: no problem. I had some path variables that weren't set properly.